# SOAPUI: Found nothing to import in [file ...\test.wsdl]

Tags: xsd, wsdl, soapui

Could anyone tell me how I fix this XSD and WSDL:

**XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="testRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="BETA"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**WSDL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="test" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/test" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/test"   
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" namespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/test">
        <xs:import namespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/test" schemaLocation="../wsdl/testRequest.xsd"/>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="testRequest">
      <wsdl:part name="testRequest" element="testsRequest"/>
   </wsdl:message>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

SOAPUI ERROR:

> Found nothing to import in [file ...\test.wsdl]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It appears that wsdl is incomplete.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I was having a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing some elements in your WSDL.

Basically a WSDL consist of;
Definitions,
Type,
Message,
Port Type,
Binding,
Service and
Port

The easiest way to understand this is to follow an example like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wsdl/wsdl_example.htm

Try loading that in your SoapUI. Confirm that everything works and then start playing around with the various elements to see what they do.